# Play streaming radio through Rhythmbox

Tags: sound, rhythmbox, streaming, internet-radio

http://prasarbharati.gov.in/playersource.php?channel=168

The link above is the official All India Radio (AIR) station / Akaashvani streaming radio channel. They have around 1000 channels based on language and region. Now that I have the URL of my favourite station, I wanted to add it to Rhyhmbox for using now and later.

Is it possible for me to listen it through Rhythmbox ? I tried, but didn't find any option. It would be great to help find a solution.

I am using 18.04. Thanks.

Edit :

Tried Gnome MPV and VLC so far, no luck. Also tried mpv media player.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that its a direct mp3 streaming link and not a link to an online player

Comment: How do we do that ? Thanks

Comment: Open the link in a browser and see if it shows a page. If it does, it wasn't a direct mp3 streaming link.

Comment: Yes, it opens a page.

Comment: But is the page a full online player with the stations logo or is it just a playback bar in the middle of the window